# iOS-14 netServiceBrowser.searchForServices Not working

Tags: swift, xcode, ios14

Recently i updated my phone to iOS 14 and since then netServiceBrowser.searchForServices(ofType:"xyz._tcp", inDomain: "local.") not working at all. iPhone is not able to discover any services and not calling any NetServiceBrowserDelegate methods.

Comment: Adding more info to this issue: App is returning this error: 
{
    NSNetServicesErrorCode = "-72008";
    NSNetServicesErrorDomain = 10;
}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your app requires access to the local network, and iOS14 has a new privacy option that requires authorization for this.

You have to add `NSLocalNetworkUsageDescription` to your Info.plist, see [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nslocalnetworkusagedescription)

Comment: Thanks Itay and i found same answer as you gave and I have figured out issue based on error code and have also added key in plist and bonjours service in plist.

Answer (score 6):

If you use Bonjour, you need to déclare it in info.plist too...

```
<key>NSBonjourServices</key>
<array>
    <string>_http._tcp</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score 1):

here is my solutions that work for me well

```
<key>NSLocalNetworkUsageDescription</key>
<string>Allow Flutter tools on your computer to connect and debug app</string>
<key>NSBonjourServices</key>
<array>
    <string>_dartobservatory._tcp</string>
</array>
```